# Evolution randomly stopped supporting my Gmail account

Tags: 11.04, evolution, gmail

I'm running 11.04 and have had Evolution linked to my Gmail for some time without a problem. All of the sudden (after no changes) it's not showing any of my folders or messages.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discover What Causes the Bug**

Starting Evolution from your terminal with some special environment variables causes Evolution to display more information on what it is currently doing.

The following is a list of variables and what each one tells Evolution to do:

```
CAMEL_DEBUG=all — used for debugging Email (Camel is the name of Evolution's Mail Access Library)
CAMEL_DEBUG=gpg — used for debugging problems with GPG encryption
CAMEL_VERBOSE_DEBUG=1 — also for debugging Email (not as featureful as above)
CALDAV_DEBUG=all — For CalDav calendars
LDAP_DEBUG=1 — For LDAP addressbooks combined with running e-addressbook-factory on a console
GROUPWISE_DEBUG=1 — used for debugging GroupWise support
E2K_DEBUG=1 — used for debugging Exchange support: Print each request and response
E2K_DEBUG=2 — Same as #1 plus all request and response headers
E2K_DEBUG=3 — Same as #2 plus bodies (except text/html)
E2K_DEBUG=4 — Same as #3 plus global catalog debug
E2K_DEBUG=5 — Same as #4 plus text/html bodies too
```

It's easy to start Evolution with custom variables. One would simply run something like the following:

```
CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution >& evo.log
```